# How find this maximum $Aa^2+Bb^2+Cc^2$ if $a+b+c=1$

Tags: inequality

let $a+b+c=1,a,b,c\ge 0$,find this following maximum
$$f(a,b,c)=Aa^2+Bb^2+Cc^2$$
where $A,B,C$ be postive constant numbers.

My idea: if find this minimum value,I can find it,because we have use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,then we have
$$(Aa^2+Bb^2+Cc^2)(\dfrac{1}{A}+\dfrac{1}{B}+\dfrac{1}{C})\ge (a+b+c)^2=1$$
so
$$Aa^2+Bb^2+Cc^2\ge\dfrac{ABC}{AB+BC+AC}$$
But find this  maximum,I can't to solve it ,Thank you for you help,

Comment: "find this maximum, I can't" You sound like yoda :)

Comment: Hint: Use $AM(x,y,z)\le \text{max}\{x,y,z\}$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Lagrange multipliers ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici,I don't think use Lagrange multipliers to solve this form inequality

Comment: Set $x^2=Aa^2, y^2=Bb^2$ and $z^2=Cc^2$, then the problem reduces to maximizing $x^2+y^2+z^2$ on the set of points $\frac{x}{\sqrt A}+\frac{y}{\sqrt B}+\frac{z}{\sqrt C}=1$, and $x,y,z>0$. Thats maximizing distance between origin and the part of the plane $$\frac{x}{\sqrt A}+\frac{y}{\sqrt B}+\frac{z}{\sqrt C}=1$$ in the first quadrant. Should occur at one of the vertices of the triangle :)

Comment: @nanchangjian. This was just a question since it makes the problem very simple. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Let $M=\text{max}\{A.B.C\}$, then
$$
Aa^2+Bb^2+Cc^2\le M(a^2+b^2+c^2)\le M(a+b+c)^2=M
$$
Obviously $M$ is attained, because $A,B$ and $C$ are attained, hence $M$ is the maximum value of your function.